# How send a message from JSF to an application in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, jsf, jsf-2

I build a `.xhtml` page which has a button `'turn on/off'`. I would like to send a message `(on or off)` from my `.xhtml` page over the internet to my application `(.java)` which is running in another network, in another computer.

I was thinking in do this with `sockets` (client / server ) but I wonder if it's the best approach.

Any idea ?

Comment: Does the JSF run as an applet?, Will you send the message to web server or is it a desktop application?

Comment: I prefer a desktop application, to avoid the necessity to use the browser, server (container) and everything else.

Comment: This is a really broad question. This is also not exactly related to JSF, so the JSF story is irrelevant here. You can just do the same thing in a plain vanilla Java application with `main()` as you would do in a JSF action method. First things you need to know: What is the communication protocol you need (or would like) to use? HTTP? SOAP? XMPP? MQ? Homegrown? What would be the data format of the data transfers? application/x-www-form-urlencoded? JSON? XML? CSV? Homegrown? Then just implement accordingly, step by step.

Comment: I just mentioned the JSF @BalusC because it has a lot of things that I don't know about it and maybe there's something that it could help  more easily.

I think TCP is a good choice of protocol so socket it's more appropriated here, what you think ?

Comment: TCP is a network protocol, I more mean the communication protocol. You seem to want to go in homegrown direction. That's going to be a lot of work. You'd rather look for some existing standard. If you would have chosen for example HTTP, you could just setup a (small) webserver (PHP? Servlet?) in the application client and use `URLConnection` or `HttpClient` in your JSF code, just the same way as you would do in a plain Java application. JSF has just to execute the same code in the action method.

Answer (score 0):

JSF comes with an event handling mechanism ([Event handling tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu3/)).  Use that to get the button press back to the server.  Then in the event handling code, send the message to the other server using sockets or JMS queues or whatever else you want.

Comment: Uhm, just doing the job in a JSF action method is more than sufficient. No need to reimplement/customize the whole event handling mechanism. OP should be well aware of this. Or have you never used JSF?

Comment: By the way, I am new to stackoverflow what does "OP" acronym stand for?

Comment: OP - Original Poster.  I agree, using the built in event handling is sufficient.  It's what I recommended - handle the event from the button using the JSF mechanism.  Then, in the JSF event handler, to talk to the other computer.